# How to login an user silently with oauth2?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0

I am building a web app for a booking platform and I am using oauth2 to use their **API** and authentificate users. My app is **embedded** in an other website named here 'X' that I am **not** in control. When the user click on my app, it loads `https://localhost/?_account_id=12`  in an iframe where `_account_id=12` is its own account id in X website.

- I am using the oauth2 **authorization code flow** so the user approves my app.
- I am storing securely the refresh token provided by the authorization server.
- I am storing in session the `account_id` parameter.
- The authorization server doesn't support the famous `prompt=none`.
- This is the first time I use oauth2 so maybe I didn't understand correctly how oauth2 works.

Since I can't only rely on the `_account_id` parameter because of security, I need to authentificate the user each time it connects to my app. Doing so, each time the session expires, the app prompted the user to approve my app.

With other apps available in X, I am never prompted to re-approve the apps. So when analysing them, the network developer tool of my browser lists this each time I connect to other apps :

**`204`** `https://other_app_provider/fr/admin?_account_id=12`

**`302`** `https://other_app_provider/auth/?_account_id=12`

**`302`** `https://authorization_server/oauth/authorize?_account_id=12&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code&scope={SCOPES}&state={STATE}`

**`302`** `https://other_app_provider/auth/bookingsync/callback?code={CODE}&state={STATE}`

***`200`*** `https://other_app_provider/admin`

I repeat that there is no approval screen between the authorization and the callback.

**My question** : How to authentificate the user silently using the **authorization code flow** or the **implicit flow** ? In other terms, how to imitate the behavior described above ?

Thank you for answering !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution :

There was an option `account_id` in X authorization server not well documented :

> **Pre-Select The Account To Authorize**
>
> When calling your Admin URL, we pass the parameter `_account_id`. The value of this parameter can be used as the `account_id` parameter during the authorization process. Doing so will pre-select the account to authorize when using the Authorization Code Flow or Implicit Flow.

So I can imitate the behavior described in the question by passing `account_id` parameter in the authorization url.

Now, I understand the term *Pre-Select* by :

> Check if the account owner is connected to the host app, select its account and silently authentificate the account owner in the app, if it's an already approved account.

If I didn't see it in the network developer tool, it was because they were provided by X, so maybe X use cookie/session to *Pre-Select* the account to authorize. I had to install third-party apps to see the `account_id` parameter in the authorization url.

Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Could I ask a few questions first - to see if I'm understanding the scenario:

- Does the user login to the host app X first and your app then gets loaded as a plug-in?
- Is this a federation scenario where different companies build the host and plug-in?
- Do the host and plug-in use the same authorization server or are they different login systems with different user credentials.

Avoiding the consent prompt may be as simple as switching this setting off in the OAuth Client entry for your app in the Authorizatiom Server

It is worth being aware that OAuth logins in an iframe are often blocked due to [clickjacking concerns](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/clickjacking) and a more reliable option is to use a pop-up window for plug-in logins.

In some scenarios it can be very hard or impossible to achieve the desired behaviour of making the solution feel like a single integrated UI - but your requirement is becoming very common.

Comment: - The user login in X website before accessing to apps
- There is no scenario unless oauth2 authorization
- The authorization server belong to X

Can you explain 'setting off in the OAuth Client entry' ?

For consent prompt we use Javascript to redirect into an iframe. Hope I'm clear ;)

Comment: So your app is using a second redirect after login. It uses a client ID that I assume you have been given. The client id references an OAuth Client Trust Entry that is configured in an admin UI something like the below link. In some cases it is possible to turn off the consent screen setting here. Can you compare the setting of your app against others that have the desired behaviour? https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oidc/identity-providers/okta